# Restrict access to All Users folder on XP and 7 via GP

Tags: security, windows-7, windows-xp, group-policy, filesystems

I am attempting to restrict access to the All Users folder via GP. Currently I have the setting under:

Computer/Policies/Windows Settings/Security Settings/File System
configured for the %AllUsersProfile% folder, which works great on XP. However it doesn't work on 7 since that points to C:\ProgramData.

Is there any other way to go about this to make it work with XP and 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe doing what you're doing will accomplish your goal. In Win 7, All Users is just a shortcut to C:\ProgramData so if you set permissions on %AllUsersProfile% there you should be good to go in both OS's.

Comment: To me it looked like C:\ProgramData contained more than just documents and desktop, so is it a good idea to restrict that folder like that?

Comment: There is nothing left but to configure it and test.